# How do you get minimum of a group and value corresponding to the minimum row of a column in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

How do I get minimum date of a group in pandas and get corresponding value of a column value in different column using pandas?

```
data = {'date_value': ['2014-06-22', '2014-06-24', '2014-06-25', '2014-06-25', '2014-07-02', '2014-07-06', '2014-07-05', '2014-07-27'],
    'type': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C'],
    'sum_col': [1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['date_value', 'type', 'sum_col'])
df['date_value'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_value'])
df[['min_date','new_sum_col']] = df.groupby('type')['date_value','sum_col'].transform('min')
```

The result I get is :

```
  date_value type  sum_col   min_date  new_sum_col
0 2014-06-22    A        1 2014-06-22            1
1 2014-06-24    A        2 2014-06-22            1
2 2014-06-25    A        3 2014-06-22            1
3 2014-06-25    B        5 2014-06-25            2
4 2014-07-02    B        4 2014-06-25            2
5 2014-07-06    B        3 2014-06-25            2
6 2014-07-05    B        2 2014-06-25            2
7 2014-07-27    C        1 2014-07-27            1
```

Result I want is :

```
   date_value type  sum_col    min_date  new_sum_col
0  2014-06-22    A        1  2014-06-22            1
1  2014-06-24    A        2  2014-06-22            1
2  2014-06-25    A        3  2014-06-22            1
3  2014-06-25    B        5  2014-06-25            5
4  2014-07-02    B        4  2014-06-25            5
5  2014-07-06    B        3  2014-06-25            5
6  2014-07-05    B        2  2014-06-25            5
7  2014-07-27    C        1  2014-07-27            1
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you,

Sam

Comment: Running example with expected and actual outputs, <enter Feels Good meme here>

Comment: @Adam.Er8 what do you mean? actual outcome and expected outcome is there in the question above.

Comment: Yea I know, and it's awesome of you to put them there :) Many people don't include any of it. I was trying to say that this is a good question lol, probably didn't say it right? sry. >_<

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `transform('first')` after sorting by the `date_value` to get both column values for the row with the minimum date:

```py
df[['min_date', 'new_sum_col']] = df.sort_values('date_value', ascending=True).groupby('type')['date_value', 'sum_col'].transform('first')
```

Comment: This is somewhat a pandas equivalent of [SQL's DISTINCT ON](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT)

Comment: Thank you so much. This is what I was looking for.  Just quick question how can i tell what are the argument this transform takes.  When I look at this documentation https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html it doesn't tell me  what it takes like "sum","last","first". How can I tell or find what it takes.  Thank you once again

Answer (score 1):

Alternative method using `idxmin`:

```
df[['min_date', 'new_sum_col']] = df.loc[df.groupby('type')['date_value'].transform('idxmin'), ['date_value', 'sum_col']].values
```

Comment: nice! I went for `idxmin` as my first approach but couldn't get it to fill all the rows >_<